# Can I affirm that the Universe is an element of this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given

$$E = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$$
$$A \subseteq P(E)$$

With axioms:

$$(1): (X \in A \land Y \in A) \implies X \cup Y \in A$$
$$(2): X \in A \implies \overline{X} \in A$$
$$(3): \{1,2,3\} \in A$$
$$(4): \{1\} \in A$$

The exercise asks me to demonstrate:

> $\emptyset \in A$

My reasoning was this:

First, I will demonstrate that the Universe $U$ is an element of $A$:

Since $\{1\} \in A$, using axiom (2) we know that $\overline{\{1\}} \in A$ as well.

Now, with axiom (1) we get that $\{1\} \cup \overline{\{1\}} \in A \implies U \in A$

Finally, since $U \in A$, with axiom (2) we can tell that $\overline{U} \in A$. The complement of the universe is always $\emptyset$, so $\emptyset \in A$

---

Was that valid? How could it have been done otherwise?

Comment: Yes, that's valid - except that the universe is called $E$ here.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I was wondering this too - I mean, how can I say that the universe is E and not something like $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You have $A \subseteq P(E)$, so $E$ is the universe of discourse here, the complement is taken with respect to $E$, $\overline{X} = E\setminus X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah, I see. Thanks! You should post that as an answer.

Comment: "How could it have been done otherwise?": you could have used $\{1,2,3\}$ instead of $\{1\}$.  

In fact, so long as $A$ is not empty, you could use any element of $A$ in exactly the same way with axioms (2), (1) and then (2) to show $\emptyset \in E$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is valid, and except for minor modifications, the only natural proof (at least, as far as I see). With one caveat, since the premise is

$$A\subseteq P(E),$$

the universe of discourse here is $E$, and the complements are to be understood with respect to $E$, so instead of $U$, you should write $E \in A$.

A minor modification that makes the proof *seemingly* more abstract would be to argue that by $(3)$ or $(4)$, there is an $X \in A$, hence by $(2)$ and $(1)$, we have $E = X \cup \overline{X} \in A$, whence (by $(2)$ again) $\emptyset = \overline{E}\in A$.